# Como formatar datetime no angular usando typeScript?

Tags: javascript

quero pegar data e hora atual no formato '2018-05-25 20:01:01'.

Tentei com javascript mas não consegui. Como faz usando angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui.

```
   var d = new Date();
    var strData =
        d.getFullYear() + "-" +
        ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
        ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " +          
        ("00" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
        ("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
        ("00" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```